# How can I frame an interface with modules in Access?

Tags: ms-access, interface

I have written a few modules of code in Access vba. Each code runs for various purpose and performs various actions on the database.
I am not too much experinced in vba. I am planning to build an 'interface' or a 'form' so that a user can select which operation he wants to perfgorm and based on that that particular code runs.

Can someone direct me to a tutorial or website which shows me some information on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is nearly always a good idea to look at the Northwind sample database: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C6661372-8DBE-422B-8676-C632D66C529C&displaylang=en

Comment: But beware that the sample dbs and templates that ship with Access have an awful lot of things in them that violate best practices (such as binding a form to a full table instead of a SQL statement, filtered or not).

Comment: I agree with Fenton: though I can't vouch for the front end, the tables, VIEW and procs are very poorly designed IMO.